# R - split string confidentiality to columns

Tags: r, string, dplyr

my dataframe looks like sort of this

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    id = seq(1, 5, 1),
    acc = c(NA_character_, "115-7981987/7121", "48415875/4874", "8740-454648484/100", "18715/7811")
  )
```

I'd like to crate 3 new columns from acc column. **Im looking for dplyr solution**

1. if there is a - symbol then get value before this symbol split
   string by / symbol, but do not include part before - symbol (in case
   that is present)

In other words, result should be exactly:

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    id = seq(1, 5, 1),
    prefix = c(NA_character_, "115", NA_character_, "8740", NA_character_),
    number = c(NA_character_, "7981987", "48415875", "454648484", "18715"),
    code = c(NA_character_, "7121", "4874", "100", "7811")
  )
```

Normaly I would use `str_split(acc, "/")` and then extract parts like this `map_chr(uuid, 1)` But this not works since some acc fields are empty, and some of them do not include all symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
         #Get a number before "-"
  mutate(prefix = str_extract(acc, "\\d+(?=-)"),
         #Get a number between "-" and "/"
         number = str_extract(acc, "(?<=-?)\\d+(?=/)"), 
         #Get a number before "/"
         code = str_extract(acc, "(?<=/)\\d+")) %>%
  select(-acc)

#  id prefix    number code
#1  1   <NA>      <NA> <NA>
#2  2    115   7981987 7121
#3  3   <NA>  48415875 4874
#4  4   8740 454648484  100
#5  5   <NA>     18715 7811
```

---

A one-liner option with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
tidyr::extract(df, acc, c("prefix", "number", "code"), "(.*?)-?(\\d+)/(\\d+)")
```

This returns blank spaces instead of `NA` for some values in `prefix` column which can be changed to `NA` if needed.

Answer (score 5):

An opting involving `tidyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 separate(acc, into = c("prefix", "number"), sep = "-", fill = "left") %>%
 separate(number, into = c("number", "code"), sep = "/")

  id prefix    number code
1  1   <NA>      <NA> <NA>
2  2    115   7981987 7121
3  3   <NA>  48415875 4874
4  4   8740 454648484  100
5  5   <NA>     18715 7811
```